# php get full url of searched keyword in google

Tags: php, url, referrer, keyword-search

I want to get full url from google search term. 
Ex. https://www.google.com/#q=michael+jackson.
So, all I want do is to grab the HTTP REFERRER joined  with full url from google search keyword(term).
 
I know that google has changed the rules because of security, but if it is any way to do that, please help me.